# Map scale factor when converting from Mercator to Equirectangular

Tags: maps, mercator

Lets say I have a map in Mercator projection, and I know top and bottom latitudes:

topLatitude = 80; bottomLatitude = -55;

I also know width and height of a map:

width = 800; height = 500;

I want to rescale the map to Equirectangular projection, keeping the same width.

How can I calculate new height of a map?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came up with a solution.

This is formula to calculate x and y of Mercator projected map:

[image]

Here is function for y:

```
function degreesToRadians(degrees){
    return degrees / 180 * Math.PI;
}

function mercatorLatitudeToY(latitude){
    return Math.log(Math.tan(Math.PI / 4 + degreesToRadians(latitude) / 2));
}
```

When R=1 the result you get is radians. So I calculate y for top and bottom latitudes.

Next, I calculate the same radians if the projection is Equirectangular - I simply need to convert top and bottom latitude to radians. And last thing - I just need to find aspect ratio of differences:

```
var scale =  (mercatorLatitudeToY(topLatitude) - mercatorLatitudeToY(bottomLatitude))/ (degreesToRadians(topLatitude) - degreesToRadians(bottomLatitude));
```

For map without Antarctica, aspect ratio is ~1.5

Comment: (1)
Mercator and Equirectangular are two different map projections. To go from Mercator to Equirectangular, you need to first (reverse) project Mercator (NE) to Lat/Long, and then (forward) project Lat/Long to Equirectangular (NE).


(2)
Mercator and Equirectangular formula each has two forms - one for ellipsoid, and one for sphere. The formula you showed is for the sphere. All digitally-available geospatial data today are basically referenced to an ellipsoid, and hence you should use the ellipsoidal form of Mercator.